# Calculating (Approximate) values of fractional powered real numbers without calculator or log/antilog tables.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, algebraic-number-theory, real-numbers

Is there any way to calculate/approximate values like $$(\frac{125}{250})^{0.66}$$ using only a pen, paper and the mind?

(Above expression being just an example, the numbers may vary and not be easy to approximate)

I've already tried the expansion method but I seek a $\mathbf {faster}$ $\mathbf{method}$ that can be used in an exam. Nothing else comes to my mind, nor could I find any other method on the internet.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can calculate logs, antilogs, sins etc using the expansion formula. Theoretically possible. Practically difficult to do.

Comment: @Aatmaj Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, I'm looking for a method that can be used in an exam and is not too time consuming.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hi @Shaun I'm not sure what else I can add to my edit regarding this question. I was just looking for someone who knows a method to approximate such values as I'm not able to find one myself. Thank you for the tip though!

Comment: Was it intentional to have the fraction reduce to $\frac12$ in the example?

Comment: @jackson No, it was just an example. They can be any random numbers like $\frac{19}{17}$ .

Comment: I have given some discussion in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371967/mental-math-estimating-logarithms) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22808/is-there-a-way-to-quickly-estimate-the-reciprocal-of-a-number/).  There are many tricks that depend on knowing facts.  How much work it is depends on how accurate you want to be.

Comment: @RossMillikan Can you please explain how these methods would help me in calculating values like $[\frac{19}{17}]^{0.66}$ ? I'm having trouble figuring out how to use approximations in log to calculate an exponential value.

Comment: See [Calculating logs and fractional exponents by hand](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793127/calculating-logs-and-fractional-exponents-by-hand)

Comment: *I'm looking for a method that can be used in an exam and is not too time consuming* --- Just what kind of exam would you need this for??

Comment: For that the first approximation comes from $(1+x)^k \approx 1+kx$ for $x,xk \ll 1$, so it would be $1+\frac 2{17}\cdot 0.66$, easy to do by hand

Comment: Not all of them are as easy.  The test maker should make sure they are.  The $.66$ looks very close to $\frac 23$ to me, so you can square and take a cube root for that part.

Comment: @RossMillikan what should I do if the condition *x* <<
 1 isn't fulfilled? For instance : $[\frac{127}{13}]^{2.66}$ .

Comment: @RossMillikan Though I don't want to take chances but I see that you have a point.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a good solution for your example with a decimal exponent, but in the title you asked about fractional powers. You can approximate these pretty easily using Newton's method. Modifying your example to $(\frac{125}{250})^\frac{2}{3}$, we can use $x_0=\frac{27}{64}$ to get $\frac{27}{64}^{\frac{2}{3}}+(\frac{125}{250}-\frac{27}{64})\frac{2}{3}(\frac{27}{64})^{-\frac{1}{3}}$. Simplifying this gives $\frac{9}{16}+\frac{5}{72}=\frac{91}{144}\approx0.632$, which is pretty close to the actual value, $0.630$. This is pretty feasible if the numerator and denominator are single digits, but once you start dealing with more complex fractions, it starts to become very difficult to find a good $x_0$, unless you're lucky enough to be able to use $x_0=1$.

We can convert any decimal exponent into a fractional exponent. For example: $(\frac{125}{250})^{0.66}=(\frac{125}{250})^\frac{66}{100}$. Unfortunately, I don't know any power of $\frac{66}{100}$ off the top of my head, aside from the trivial $x_0=1$, so we'll use that. We get $1+(\frac{125}{250}-1)\frac{66}{100}(1)^{-\frac{34}{100}}=\frac{66}{100}=0.66$, which is sort of close to $0.633$.

If we always use $x_0=1$, we can get a formula of $x^n=1+nx-n$, which is easy to memorize, and works reasonably well for values from $n<x<\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this! Can you just explain what $ \mathit x _0$ is defined as in the first example and the formula if we don't use $ \mathit x _0$ =1?

Comment: We want $x_0$ to be as close to the base of the exponent as possible, while still having and exponent that's easy to calculate. In my first example, we chose $\frac{27}{64}$, because its pretty close to $\frac{125}{250}$, and because we already know the exponent: $(\frac{27}{64})^\frac{2}{3}=\frac{9}{16}$

Comment: We then use the formula $f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0)$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!